# hive unix timestamp milliseconds

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

I am storing dates as strings, but want to select where the date meets a certain criteria.

Dates look like this ... "2014-10-09 03:59:14.0"

The dates have a millisecond, do I need to remove that millisecond?

This select is running but is not producing the right results.

```
select EVENT_DT_TM from yv_ipc where unix_timestamp(event_dt_tm,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S") >         unix_timestamp("2014-10-09 03:59:13.0","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S") limit 10;
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: _I am storing dates as strings_ - don't. Store dates as DateTime. This will bite you repeatedly otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried creating this field as a timestamp, but it returns NULL when I select from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the data loaded with double quotes around every field. Hence being unable to perform the date manipulation.